# UAP file extensions

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

My package.appxmanifest editor wont open in the designer in the new VS 2015 RC so I'm forced to edit it the old fashioned way. How can I add file extensions to a windows universal app(windows 10) like this one from an 8.1 app:

```
<Extensions>

<Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">

<FileTypeAssociation Name="mp3">

<DisplayName>mp3</DisplayName>

<SupportedFileTypes>

<FileType>.mp3</FileType>

<FileType>.wma</FileType>

<FileType>.wav</FileType>

</SupportedFileTypes>

</FileTypeAssociation>

</Extension>

</Extensions>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add file extensions like this:

```
 <Applications>
<Application Id="App"
  Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
  EntryPoint="MultipleWindows.App">
  <Extensions><uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="jpsmv">
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        <uap:FileType>.jpsMV</uap:FileType>  
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        </uap:FileTypeAssociation>  
    </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>        
  <uap:VisualElements
```

Ref:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn934796.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I noticed a typo in the documentation:           <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
     <uap:FileType>.alsdkjs</uap:FileType>
</SupportedFileTypes> should be
               
   <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:FileType>.alsdkjs</uap:FileType>
    </uap:SupportedFileTypes>

Comment: Thanks @shady I appreciate you pointing that out and I filed a doc bug!  (I didn't catch it because I typed it in myself in my project and autocomplete did the right thing.)